# Изменение элемента через jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

мой код:

```
 $(#userStatus1).append('admin');
 <td id='userStatus1'>1</td>
```

хром матерится ошибкой:

> (index):161 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

почему не работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что селектор должен быть строкой:

```
 $('#userStatus1').append('admin');
 <td id='userStatus1'>1</td>
```

Comment: а если с  $(document).ready(function() { ????

Comment: @Ostap34PHP ну вообще ещё может быть `document`, `window`, это jQuery DOM селеторы, но в вашем случае просто надо всё в виде строки записать

Comment: а что отличает етод код от оригинала?

Comment: @Ostap34PHP, кавычки вокруг `#userStatus1`.

Comment: спасибо большое!